# How to stop sqlplus command in unix shell script when any sql fails

Tags: bash, shell, unix, build-automation, devops

I am new to shell script . 
i am writing a code for DBA automation in which i have master.sql file have declarations of n number of sqls . and these sqls are placed inside particular folder . 
i have a script which is calling this master.sql and executing those sqls at once indirectly and saving in the log file

sqlplus command is saving the output of all the sqls declared inside master.sql at once 
wwhat i want is it must stop the execution when the first sql fails and return the error witht the specific sql which failed or ask to rollback and asking do you want to continue or not ?
tried using sqlplus whenever,, sqlerror ,$? nothing worked

```
sqlplus  ${USER}/${PASS}@$SID  @master.sql > /home/deploy/vidya/properties/result/result.log
```

Now what i am trying to do is .... i want to stop the execution of sqls when any of the sql fails from the starting and prompts on the command line with the error and specify which sql fails

***master.sql***

```
SET ECHO ON

@/home/deploy/vidya/properties/001_dba_demo.sql
@/home/deploy/vidya/properties/003_dba_demo1.sql
@/home/deploy/vidya/properties/002_dba_demo2.sql
@/home/deploy/vidya/properties/004_dba_demo2.sql

EXIT
```

my .sh script which is calling master.sql and its working properly

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter schema Name you want to connect: "
read USER
echo "Enter password: "
read -s PASS
#echo "Enter Oracle SID for the environment you want to connect with  : "
#read SID
echo "Enter Environment for the environment you want to connect with  : "
read ENV
echo "Enter Oracle SID for the environment you want to connect with  : "
read SID

 export ORACLE_SID=${SID}

if [ $ENV ==  UAT ]
then
   echo "Connected withh UAT ORACLE HOME:"
export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0.4/db_1
elif [ $ENV == PROD ]
then
echo "Connected with PROD ORACLE HOME:"
export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0.4/db_1

else
 echo "Wrong Environment Entered :"

fi
export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH

echo "want to execute sql? y/n"
read yn

sqlplus  ${USER}/${PASS}@$SID  @master.sql > /home/deploy/vidya/properties/result/result.log
```

**

can anyone help?**

Comment: [WHENEVER SQLERROR](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12052.htm) ?

Answer (score 0):

One ideea would be to launch the sql's in sequence and check them afterwards for errors:
e.g.

```
sqlplus  ${USER}/${PASS}@$SID  @dba_demo.sql > /home/deploy/vidya/properties/result/result_dba_demoSQL.log
checker = $(grep "ERROR" result_dba_demoSQL.log) 
if [ test -z $checker ]
   then echo "dba_demo_SQL successfull run"
   else 
       echo "dba_demo_SQL failed"
       exit 0
fi
```

The exit 0 part, exits the whole script when grep find an error in the log file.

Comment: If you don't want to write too many ifs in the script, you can put the whole thing in a for: e.g. for f in `ls -1 /some_location/folder_with_sqls`; do the_if_part_above; done. you can use the f in 'for f in...' as a variable for launching certain scripts: sqlplus ${USER}/${PASS}@$SID  @$f and saving output to certain log file: > /home/deploy/vidya/properties/result/result_$f.log, And modifying the checker variable $(grep "ERROR" result_$f.log

Comment: An sql failure should probably be treated as an error.  Print the error message to stderr, and exit with a non-zero value:  `... else; echo "dba_demo_SQL failed" >&2; exit 1; `

Comment: Agree with William, better to use exit 1

Comment: i guess sqlplus has the main feature to execute the sqls at once and saving it in log file . it is doing it already . what i want is to execute every sql one by one and if any sql fails then it should stop the execution and give the error on command line

Answer (score 0):

i guess sqlplus has the main feature to execute the sqls at once and saving it in log file . it is doing it already . what i want is to execute every sql one by one and if any sql fails then it should stop the execution and give the error on command line

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for not using comments. Don't have enough reputation. 
That's my solution in the first answer.
Instead of launching the master.sql via sqlplus, launch the smaller sqls one by one and check the log file after each execution.
If the log file for sql number 1 has errors, the exit 1 in the if clause will terminated the whole script.

```
    #First query 
    #Sqlplus command to run the first query 
    sqlplus  ${USER}/${PASS}@$SID  @dba_demo.sql > /home/deploy/vidya/properties/result/result_dba_demoSQL.log 
    #variable checker is assigned ERROR, if ERROR is found in file (you have to check what errors you can get from oracle)
    checker = $(grep "ERROR" result_dba_demoSQL.log)
    #If clause that checks if variable checker is empty or not, if variable checker is empty, it means that no string "ERROR" was found in log files, thus script continues to run; If variable is not empty (string ERROR was chatched) script terminates. 
    if [ test -z $checker ]
       then echo "dba_demo_SQL successfull run"
       else 
           echo "dba_demo_SQL failed"
           exit 1
    fi 
    # Second Query
    sqlplus  ${USER}/${PASS}@$SID  @dba_demo1.sql > /home/deploy/vidya/properties/result/result_dba_demo1SQL.log
    checker = $(grep "ERROR" result_dba_demo1SQL.log) 
    if [ test -z $checker ]
       then echo "dba_demo1_SQL successfull run"
       else 
           echo "dba_demo1_SQL failed"
           exit 1
    fi
```

Comment: This is the good solution but the thing is i am doing dba automation and doin this for client so its their requirement . they send us the master.sql file have declarataion of all the sqls . so we have to execute it . . so can you help using this method only ?

Answer (score 0):

If your master.sql is the same as the example you posted, meaning a list of paths to sql files themselves, you can do this:

```
    # Read the master.sql file, for every line in master.sql file 
    for i in `cat master.sql`; do
    # basename "$i" takes the name of the file from path present in master.sql 
    sql_name = $(basename "$i")
    # use path in the sqlplus command ($i from the for loop) and sqlname for the log file name
    sqlplus  ${USER}/${PASS}@$SID  @$i > /home/deploy/vidya/properties/result/result_$sql_name.log
checker = $(grep "ERROR" result_$sql_name.log) 
if [ test -z $checker ]
   then echo "$sql_name successfull run"
   else 
       echo "$sql_name failed"
       exit 1
fi ; done
```

Comment: error:                                                                                                                                               ./run-sqlplus2.sh: line 96: =: command not found
exit
grep: .log: No such file or directory
./run-sqlplus2.sh: line 99: checker: command not found
./run-sqlplus2.sh: line 100: [: test: unary operator expected
 failed